# Git auto merge code from one branch to another branch inside same repo

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have 2 branches Branch A and Branch B, I need to merge the code from Branch A to merge in Branch B as soon as someone pushes code in Branch A.
Is there any tool or configuration available to achieve this?

Comment: On the server, you will need to add a "post-receive hook". See "man githooks". The general code will be universal, though some of the finer implementation details of this may be specific to your hosting platform (e.g. gitolite, GitLab, GitHub, etc.) Also, you may want to think about what happens if there are merge conflicts.

Comment: Taking the longer route, you could also have your CI process do the same - after vetting that the commit(s) in the source branch are "good" - by whatever definition is being followed in your repo/team.